# Awk to append out to array for further processing

Tags: arrays, bash, awk, bind

Hoping to pick your brains on something that my current bash skills is not able to compute;)

Parsing a named.conf file for reference to filenames of actual zonefiles, that I would like to copy to a directory for migration purposes. First step, I had an idea about placing the paths to the zonefiles into an array as part of the awk operation. Coming out of the initial parsing loop, I could then loop through the array find new references (to .db files below) and copy the files. Ultimately, as part of the copy of the zonefiles I was hoping to rename the target files with a reference to the domainname (e.g. domaina.com).

So, I have create an input file containing the domains e.g:

```
cat domains.txt
domaina.com
domainb.com
domainc.com
```

the named.conf.deployed will include a section (like below) of each of the domains in question.

```
// zone: domaina.com [slave]
include "/etc/active/1704500.conf";
```

Now, over to what I have accomplished so far - which isn't much :( As you can tell, the script only manages to parse the file and print the paths for the zones included in the domains.txt file.

```
while read p; do
grep -A2 "$p" /jail/named/etc/named.conf.deployed | grep include | awk -F\" '{print $(NF-1)}'
done <domains.txt
```

Output from script above would be:

```
/etc/active/1704500.conf
```

Instead of printing the result, can I append to an array by expanding the awk statement? Or as @David suggested us tmp file for output. Next step will be to open the files (e.g. /etc/active/1704500.conf) and do a similar parsing as the file I'm really after is buried in the .conf file (see contents 1704500.conf below).

```
// zone: domaina.com
zone "domaina.com"
{
type slave;
file "4725680.db";
};
```

Finally, copy  (in above sample) the 4725680.db file and rename it domaina.com. That is what I'm looking to accomplish in the next loop or code block.

Cheers,
Fredrik

Pls excuse all my edits, new to this and need to learn (fast) how to explain and pass sufficient info about my challenge(s).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Much simpler (assuming I'm understanding the problem) to do everything in awk.

```
$ cat domains.txt
domaina.com
domainb.com
domainc.com


$ cat named.conf.deployed
// zone: domaina.com [slave]
include "/etc/active/1704500.conf";

// zone: domainx.com [slave]
include "/etc/active/XXXX.conf";

// zone: domainc.com [slave]
include "/etc/active/CCCCC.conf";

// zone: domainb.com [slave]
include "/etc/active/BBBB.conf";


$ cat domconf.awk
NR == FNR { domains[$1]; next }

$2 == "zone:" { flag = ($3 in domains) }

$1 == "include" && flag { print clean($2); flag = 0 }

function clean(s) {
    gsub("\";?", "", s)
    return s
}


$ awk -f domconf.awk domains.txt named.conf.deployed
/etc/active/1704500.conf
/etc/active/CCCCC.conf
/etc/active/BBBB.conf
```

> NR == FNR { domains[$1]; next }

`NR == FNR` means we are reading the first file. Read the domains into an awk array. `next` skips the actions below and goes immediately to reading the next domain.

> $2 == "zone:" { flag = ($3 in domains) }

(Getting here means we are reading the second file.) If it's a "zone" comment, check the array for the domain.

> $1 == "include" && flag { print clean($2); flag = 0 }

If the domain was found, print the include name (removing the quotes) and reset the flag.

**EDIT**
 to include domain name in output:

```
$ cat domconf.awk
NR == FNR { domains[$1]; next }

$2 == "zone:" { prev_domain = $3; flag = ($3 in domains) }

$1 == "include" && flag { print prev_domain, clean($2); flag = 0 }

function clean(s) {
    gsub("\";?", "", s)
    return s
}

$ awk -f domconf.awk domains.txt named.conf.deployed
domaina.com /etc/active/1704500.conf
domainc.com /etc/active/CCCCC.conf
domainb.com /etc/active/BBBB.conf
```

Comment: Very interesting @jas ! Thanks! Is there a way to add the domainname associated with the path? e.g. 
domaina.com      /etc/active/1704500.conf

Comment: You're very welcome, @frekn0. See edit for version including the domain name associated with the path.

Comment: your suggestion of course works wonders -- again big thanks for that! If you have a minute or two, for clarification NR == FNR can this be read as append to array until end of file 1? Or is this caused "only" by 'next', if so how do I interpret the NR == FNR condition? Found this useful tutorial http://www.math.utah.edu/docs/info/gawk_11.html , but couldn't quite figure this out...

Comment: This explains it quite well:  http://backreference.org/2010/02/10/idiomatic-awk/  Search for the section headed "Two-file processing".

Comment: The key thing is that  `FNR == NR` is only true when awk is reading the first file.  That's because `FNR` is the record number within the current file, and `NR` is the record number overall that just keeps increasing. (So at the start of the second file, `FNR` will again be 1, but `NR` will be one bigger than the number of records in the first file.)  What `next` does is say "skip all the rest of the actions and go right to reading the next line of the current file".  That means that any record that makes it passed the first line, must be from the second file!

Comment: You can almost think of the `next` as an `else` in this case.  "If you're reading the first file, add the domain to the array, else do all that other stuff below."  (If that's more confusing than helpful, forget I said anything :)

Answer (score 0):

I find your question hard to understand, but I think this is what you mean:

```
arr=()             # empty array
arr+=('foo')       # add new element
arr+=('bar')       # add new element
echo ${arr[@]}     # print what we've got
foo bar

# add new elements from awk command
arr+=($(awk -F: 'NR>10 && NR<14 {print $1}' /etc/passwd))

# see what we have now
echo ${arr[@]}
foo bar nobody root daemon
```

Answer (score 0):

You're *grepping* while *awking*? Shame, shame shame...

You can eliminate the chain, and use awk to find the lines you're using grep to do:

```
$ grep "foo"  | awk '{print $2}'
$ awk '/foo/ {print $2}'
```

do the same thing. Awk can *grep* out lines just like grep can.

Your explanation and example are a wee bit short of what you want to do. I think you want to keep `etc/active/1704500.conf` and associate it with `domaina.com`. That is, you want an *associative array*. Right?

Although many people treat `awk` as another version of `cut`, it's really a programming language in its own right. Awk assumes a loop, and you put your program in that loop. Awk also has a `BEGIN` and `END` clause to do pre-loop and post-loop processing.

What you might want to do, is instead of creating an array in Awk, have your `awk` program print out the two fields you want which you can then process in another loop:

```
while read p
do
     awk '.......' >> awk.temp.$$
done
while read domain file
do
    ....
done < awk.temp.$$
rm awk.temp.$$
```

And the `awk` program could look something like this:

```
awk  '
    /\/\/ zone:/  {
    machine = $3
    getline
    file = substr( $2, 2, length ($2) - 3 )
    print machine  " " file
}' test.txt
```

The `/\/\/ zone:/` is looking for that regular expression. I save the third field of that string to the variable `machine`. The `getline` gets me to the next line. I then use `substr` and `length` to take the second word (which is the file name surrounded by quotes) and then strip out the beginning quote and the ending quote/semicolon.

Awk isn't *part of the shell*, so variables in Awk won't survive beyond the context of the `awk` program. Creating an array in Awk won't help.

I only have Bash 3.2 on my system, so I don't have associative arrays that are in Bash 4. However, maybe it's possible to manipulate the output in Awk to allow you to use it to create an associative array.

I'm not 100% sure, and I can't test this, but you could do something like this:

```
awk  '
    BEGIN { printf "(" }
    END   { print ")" }
    /\/\/ zone:/  {
    machine = $3
    getline
    file = substr( $2, 2, length ($2) - 3 )
    printf "[" machine "]=" file " "
}' test.txt
```

The awk would output something like this:

```
([machine]=/etc/file [machine2]=/etc/file2)
```

which could then be used to initialize a shell associative array.

Comment: Thank you so much @David! I think your first option w tmpfile is something I can grasp and continue to work on. Like you said, probably need both fields: domain and path in the file. This should allow for me to copy and rename the zonefiles in the next loop. I will save the associated array business for future endeavours :) Tried to clarify slightly in my edit. Also noted the grep while awk remark - will refrain from it going fwd ;)